# Вывод картинки в окно PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, изображения, pysimplegui

Хочу чтобы картинка выводилась из файла и обновлялась, делаю так

```
def ShowImage(DirectoryFile,Img,CommentFile,Image1):

    layout = [
        [sg.In(DirectoryFile,key="-DirectoryFile-"),sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("Image Files", ("*.jpg","*.png")),), key="-Img-")],
        [sg.InputText(CommentFile,key="-CommentFile-")],
        [sg.Image(Image1,key="-Image-")],
        [sg.Button("Обновить"),sg.Submit("Сохранить")]
        ]

    window = sg.Window('Получение файла', layout)
    event, values = window.read()

    while event not in (None, "Exit"):
        if event == "Обновить":
            window.close()
            ShowImage(values['-DirectoryFile-'],values['-Img-'],values['-CommentFile-'],values['-DirectoryFile-'])
        if event == "Сохранить":
            window["-IMAGE-"].update(values["-DirectoryFile-"])
```

вы дает такую ошибку при обновление
[image: Ошибка при обновление]